# RxJS combine ObjectA emissions into ObjectB Array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code grabbing data from a web service

```
@Effect()
searchAction$ : Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType(ActionTypes.SEARCH_CASES)
    .do(val => this._store.dispatch(new SetLoadingAction(true)))
    .map(action => action.payload) //just interested in the payload
    .map(payload => new CaseSearchCriteria(payload)) //form search criteria
    .switchMap(payload => this._httpSearchCases.searchDiseaseCases(payload)
        /*
            1. Return from httpCall is IDiseaseControlCaseManagement[]
            2. Transform this array into SearchDiseaseCaseResults[]
         */
        .do((val) =>{
            console.log('Type of Value: ', typeof val);
            console.log('Is value SearchDiseaseCaseResult? :', val instanceof SearchDiseaseCaseResults);
        })
        .map(res => new LoadSearchResultsAction(res))
    );
```

I have added comments briefly explaining my desired functionality, I'm certain there is a ReactiveX operator that can achieve this, however I am unable to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I tried pushing to the accumulator of the `.scan` operator

```
.scan((acc: SearchDiseaseCaseResults[], val: IDiseaseControlCaseManagement) => {
            acc.push(new SearchDiseaseCaseResults(val));
        })
```

However TS static analysis tells me this is incorrect,

```
Error:(32, 31) TS2453:The type argument for type parameter 'R' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.


Type argument candidate 'SearchDiseaseCaseResults[]' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'void'.
```

So I need an operator chain (or method) that will allow me to **either**:

1. Receive an emission of type ObjectA.
2. Transform emission of type ObjectA into object of type ObjectB
3. Receive emissions of type ObjectB
4. Combine each emission of ObjectB into a single array ObjectB[]

**or**

1. Receive an emission of type ObjectA[]
2. Transform emission of type ObjectA[] into array of type ObjectB[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless i'm misunderstanding you, then the operator you're looking for is just the plain old `map`.

Taking a step back, let's focus on your switchMap.

```
.switchMap(payload => this._httpSearchCases.searchDiseaseCases(payload)

         //    1. Return from httpCall is IDiseaseControlCaseManagement[]
        .map(IDiseaseControlCaseManagementArray => this.mapToSearchDiseaseCaseResultsArray(IDiseaseControlCaseManagementArray) )

        .do((val) =>{
            console.log('Type of Value: ', typeof val);
            console.log('Is value SearchDiseaseCaseResult? :', val instanceof SearchDiseaseCaseResults);
        })
        .map(res => new LoadSearchResultsAction(res))
    );
```

I think that's basically what you're asking - the implementation of that `mapToSearchDiseaseCaseResultArray` method.

And, if you can map a single `IDiseaseControlCaseManagement` to a single `SearchDiseaseCaseResult`, then really, implementing the array version of that is simple.

So, assuming that there is a method `convertFrom` that can be used like:

```
searchDiseaseCaseResult = convertFrom(iDeseaseControlCaseManagement)
```

Then, with the arrays,

```
mapToSearchDiseaseCaseResultArray(sourceArray) {
  return sourceArray.map(caseManagement => this.convertFrom(caseManagement));
}
```

You, of course, still need to write your `convertFrom` method to convert a single item, but once you do, you can plug it in to the method above.

Does the above make sense?

Comment: Thank you, I honestly don't know why I couldn't think of this (I guess I was trying too hard to use RxJS)